# How to open app window on toolbar click in safari app extension?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, safari-app-extension

I'd like to open an application/extension Window when user clicks toolbar item in safari. This is not question about extension's `Popover` feature. The main reason is to close/hide the window on deactivation AND user action (both conditions are required to work).

Safari App Extension (meaning the new preferred/forced way to create extensions for safari by Apple) can open a Popover or call a Command when toolbar item is clicked. But it cannot be hidden programatically (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/105817). Per answer by bweinstein it's work in progress by apple devs.

**My use case is about Window containing WKWebView with loaded webpage. When user clicks anything in there I want to open a page in Safari's new tab (this part already works for me in Popover mode) and close the window immediately (this doesn't work for me yet)**

So my thinking here was to avoid integrated Popover feature. I'd like to show Window instead when Command (`override func toolbarItemClicked(in window: SFSafariWindow) {}`) is called.

I know this is somehow doable as e.g. agilebits' 1Password extension is doing exactly this: when you click a toolbar item, window is displayed having no close/minimize buttons, no menu etc. It works exactly as I need, but I don't know how to achieve that.

**I don't know whether to define the view as part of Safari extension or as part of Storyboard of containing app and how to access it programatically and show it on screen when user clicks the toolbar item.**

As I am new to macos development I don't really have a code to share. Important part from my POV:
- Info.plist's `NSExtension->SFSafariToolbarItem->Action` is set to `Command`

As pointed above, feature I need to achieve is to open and close a Window programatically when user clicks toolbar item.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think what 1Password is doing is launching their desktop app using either custom URL scheme or a distributed notification if the app is already running.

Comment: Also see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1534059-runningapplications?language=objc
But not sure if this is available inside the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not call SFSafarWindow.openTab("httxxx://mysite.com", true, ...) in your toolbarItemClicked

You could also call SFSafariApplication.openWindow API and close SFSafariWindow (by calling windowObject.close() ) -